# What is the difference between doing parallel processing and running many RStudio sessions in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

My question is as the title.
For example, I may do a parallel processing using the `foreach` package as below:

```
# creating, registering, and dispersing clusters are omitted for concision.
foreach(i = 1:n) %dopar% {
  some tasks
}
```

and can do the same task with a simple loop in many RStudio session:

```
for(i in 1:n){
the same task
}
```

Let's say the machine has 16 cores and I use 15 cores for the parallel processing and 15 RStudio sessions are run for normal processing(I assume that each core take care each RStudio session).

Then what are the differences between the two ways?

Comment: Is there a specific result you're trying to achieve? As it stands, your question is probably overly broad (but it's still unclear to me why you would run the same loop multiple times in different RStudio instances instead of just using built-in language parallelism to actually be able to actually parallelize the task)

Comment: @HoldenRohrer Thank you for your comment. I have a complex task which should be applied to each big csv file. Currently, I have an Rscript which is not written for the parallel processing. I ask the question as I need more work to modify my script. For your information, my code has two for loops inside a parent loop (which will be done for each file). I am considering do the two nested loops using `foreach` function.